# How can I achieve index per organisation model in ElasticSearch 7?

Tags: elasticsearch

we are trying to add Elasticsearch to our web app for search purpose. I want to achieve index per organization since each organization have their own tasks, notes, documents and other organizations cannot view the data.
How can I achieve this in Elasticsearch 7 since types are deprecated?
The initial idea is to have an index for each organization and different types for each action(tasks, notes..). I am new to Elasticsearch and any insights are really helpful.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Depends on the data you will have in each doc, you can have a variety of doc in one indice

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, this is exactly what I am looking for. How to create variety of doc in single indice? For example I have an index named Animals, how can I have a document for omnivores, herbivores and carnivores in Animals index?

Comment: just index them on the same indice, you cannot specify a _type they will share the indice mapping `_doc`, but all doc do not necessary need to fill all fields

Comment: Insteading of adding in the same indice, how about creating an indice for each entity(omnivores...) and create an alias for all the related set of indices and search in alias. Please suggest.